# Preprocess function for targeting the home page

Tags: theming, 8

What's the preprocess function for targeting the home page in a Drupal 8 site? Can I use a preprocess function that is called only for the home page?

Comment: The home/front page is now a page view called **Frontpage** with url/path of `/node` so you may have to give more details on what you're trying to achieve with the preprocess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To target the front page in a preprocess function you need a condition, because for preprocess you can't use name suggestions:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['is_front']) {
    // your code
  }
}
```

Comment: not working on latest today D9

Answer (score 1):

What you call home page, for Drupal is the front page. The suggestion given by [`system_theme_suggestions_page()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_theme_suggestions_page/8.2.x), an implementation of [`hook_theme_suggestion_HOOK()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK/8.2.x) from the System module, is page__front; similarly, [`system_theme_suggestions_html()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_theme_suggestions_html/8.2.x) suggests html__front. Both the suggestions are for the preprocess functions and the template files.

If by *home page* you mean a page that is not the front page, you need to write your own `hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK()` implementation that gives the right suggestion for that page. Keep in mind that the suggested template file is used only if it exists; otherwise, Drupal will use a different suggestion, or the default template file, if none of the suggested template files exist.

Answer (score 0):

On today  latest D9, you have:

```
 function THEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
   if (\Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage()) {
      // do something for your frontpage
   }
 }
```