# How to remove Home title from the home page?

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

There are several posts on a similar question. Despite that, I couldn't find the best way to resolve it. Display Suite is installed but don't see option to turn off page title. Our home page content type is Slider. I can see the html code using Inspect Element on Firefox. Don't know where the page is to remove it.

Comment: You can use `theme_preprocess_page`  target the front page and remove the title, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/211793/preprocess-function-for-targeting-the-home-page

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to remove it from the BO:
You can use code to remove it something like:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function myTheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if($variables['is_front']){
    drupal_set_title('');
  }
}
```